# text-align: center !important; is not working?

Tags: css

this is my CSS code, i do not understand why  `text-align: center;` is not working?

```
embed, iframe, object, video {
    max-width: 98%;
    min-width: 97%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the mark up also so that we can reproduce the problem. Here is a link to a guide on how to ask a question to get the best chance of it being solved https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to center it you can try something like:

```
embed, iframe, object, video {display: block; width: 97%; margin: 0 auto; }
```

By the way you should avoid using space when adding !important to a property.

Comment: Thanks this is working perfect. display: block; and margin: 0 auto; have fix all, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to embed the objects into a `<p>` or `<a>` element.
Then:

```
p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: i know this, thanks but this do not help.